# How to pass cURL as the source of my webview

Tags: react-native

I need to pass cURL as the source of my webview in my expo app

this is the sample url

```
curl https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/ \
  --header "X-Api-Key: d82016f839e13cd0a79afc0ef5b288b3" \
  --header "X-Auth-Token: 3827881f669c11e8dad8a023fd1108c2" \
  --data "allow_repeated_payments=False&amount=2500&buyer_name=John+Doe&purpose=FIFA+16&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fredirect%2F&phone=9999999999&send_email=True&webhook=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwebhook%2F&send_sms=True&email=foo%40example.com"
```

https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/create-a-request

The below URL is working fine and fetching me data but I need the same behavior with the above url

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }} 
  onMessage={event => {
           alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
         }}style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />

</View>
```